# AD LDS data refreshing from script

Tags: ldap, openldap, ad-lds, identity-management

I need to setup a white pages servers located into a DMZ, which contains up to date identities information gathered from a remote `OpenLDAP` server with a specific account.

I cannot enable `syncrepl` ont this server, AND I must use `AD LDS` as the destination LDAP Server technology.

**So, basically the identified process is**:

- Once a day, gather all remote data in old-fashioned LDIFv3 style;
- Push the modifications (added or deleted entries) to the AD LDS Server.

**My question is**: how can I replicate the remote modifications without implying any AD LDS data loss or white pages service interruption? I thought about a batch script using `ldifde` as working force.

Thank you very much by advance for you help.

Best regards,

Kilian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly support [lsc-project](http://lsc-project.org/wiki/). An OpenSource project aimed to do exaclty what you are looking for. Have e look at the documentation pages: there are examples about OpenLDAP -> AD sync.

Comment: Yes, I already use it in other projects, but was expecting a AD LDS built-in solution. Thanks for your answer!

Nevertheless, did you hear about a web frontend of LSC?